# Routes ambiguity when debugging and change the code in controller in ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I change anything in the Asp.Net Core controller code and save changes while app is running, controller stops to work and I start to receive route ambiguity exception.

The reason is when the code is changed, the previous instance of the controller with original code, or maybe reference to it, still stays in the routing table, so I get two exactly the same routes indeed subject for an ambiguity. The only resolution is to get rid of Hot Reload or restart debugging.

Is this something well-known and I just missed it, or it's new? My Visual Studio 2022 is 17.7.3

Comment: It seems your hot reload not working as expected, Here is a discussing in this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44857), hope it can give you some help.